# Creating rough sketched shapes

Tags: shapes, drawing

[image]
I am not a professional designer however I need to make a few shapes like the ones shown above for my college presentation. I would like to ask how I can create shapes like these ?

Comment: Hi Little Child this is an easily answered question if you tell us what graphic design programs you have access to. This would most easily be completed in Adobe Illustrator.

Comment: To clarify: you want polygons like the above with a "rough sketch" look to them?

Comment: If you are a little child, it should be super easy. Just grab some crayons. :)

Comment: @DA01 I am a toddler in college. Yes. :D

Comment: @horatio Yes ! That is what I mean

Comment: @AdamSchuld I have Gimp.

Comment: Hmm this might be too simple for answer but.. when I aim for this look I just repeat the lines I make. It should be very easy to do in gimp or any other raster editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably even just draw them freehand in any drawing program on your computer.  Here's what I managed with [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/):

[image: Really crude freehand pentagon]

This despite the fact that drawing freehand lines with the mouse is really frustrating.  (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> is your friend.)  A tablet and a stylus would probably work even better.

Answer (score 3):

1. Draw the shapes on paper
2. Scan the drawings into whatever image editor you have

If you were a designer, you'd probably next go into Illustrator and live trace the shapes to give you scalable vector objects. Since you're just creating a presentation, scans are likely to be good enough.

Answer (score 1):

The terms you are looking for are polygon, **path**, and **stroke**. You will make a shape, which is usually a *path*. You then apply a *stroke* to it, and--if the software supports it--instead of a standard line style (aka a rule), the stroke uses a brush or other tool to stroke the path.

In GIMP, there is a stroke path feature. you want to use the option to "use a paint tool" (see: http://docs.gimp.org/2.6/en/gimp-path-stroke.html ). The exact tool and brush style(s) you apply is a matter of taste, so you will need to experiment a little.